# Switch from master to another branch results in error: cannot stat ... Permission denied

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

I switched to `master` branch and now want to switch back to earlier branch say `release` with `git checkout release`

But it results into error -

```
error: cannot stat '<some-directory-path>': Permission denied
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner and access rights on the mentioned directory :

```
ls -ld <some-directory-path>
```

---

Is it possible that you ran some action (either a git action like `git checkout`, or some action which creates some files, like `make` or `gulp` or ...) as another user, or with an unusual umask ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late but on Windows 10 I often find that Atom interferes with locking some of the files. Normally when i run into crap like this, closing Atom seems to fix it. I haven't investigated whether its the git portion of atom or just Atom itself.